# How to find subsequences of identical elements in an array

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I am looking for an algorithm for my hobby task.

For example we have test data cases:

```
var case1 = ['green', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green'];
var case2 = ['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'orange', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green'];
var case3 = ['purple', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red'];
```

Output:

```
var result1 = ['red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green'];
var result2 = ['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green'];
var result3 = ['blue', 'blue', 'blue'];
```

Can anybody tell me which algorithm I should use? The classic way with duplicates - not like I looking.

Comment: Do you mean identical consecutive elements because that first one is missing the first "green"?

Comment: I do not think you will need a specific algorithm for this task. Just run a loop, check if current item is equals to the previous one.

Comment: Please do not use any language tag in this type of algorithmic question, specially when you do not put any of your existing attempt to that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version

we can use the `.filter` function to achieve this behavior.

```js
.filter((item, i, array) => array[i - 1] == item || item == array[i + 1])
```

```js
let case1 = ['green', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green'];
let case2 = ['blue', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'orange', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green'];
let case3 = ['purple', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red'];

let result1 = case1.filter((item, i, array) => array[i - 1] == item || item == array[i + 1])
let result2 = case2.filter((item, i, array) => array[i - 1] == item || item == array[i + 1])
let result3 = case3.filter((item, i, array) => array[i - 1] == item || item == array[i + 1])

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
console.log(result3)
```

out of bounds index in javascript will return `undefined` which will evaluate to `false` in your comparison

Answer (score 1):

So in javascript a naive implementation would be:

```
function selectSequential(source) {
   var result = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
      if ((i != source.length-1 && source[i+1] === source[i]) 
            || (i != 0 && source[i-1] === source[i])) {
         result.push(source[i]);
      }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is what i looking for. I will analyze how it works.